# Importing coordinates from CSV - Python

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I am new to python and i am trying to import a set of x,y coordinates from csv into python.

currently my script looks as below:

```
with open ('filename.csv') as csvfile:
    data = list(tuple(rec) for rec in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ","))
```

this provides me with a list of coords as below (when printed):

```
[('1', '2'), ('5', '6'), ('4', '4'), ('8', '9')]
```

However i need the output to look as below so that it can be passed successfully into a point in polygon test.

```
[(1, 2), (5, 6), (4, 4), (8, 9)]
```

Can anyone recommend how i would change my script to achieve the result above?

Comment: N.B.: if you're using Python 2, it should be `open('filename.csv','rb')`; Python 3, `open('filename.csv', 'r', newline='')`.

Comment: Also, the `delimiter=","` on the `csv.reader()` call isn't necessary because, not too surprisingly, that's the default for CSV ([Comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do it, but I think this is the shortest (when using the csv module, with just a `open` alone it could be shorter):

```
with open('filename.csv') as csvfile:
    data = [(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')]
```

Comment: That's great, i added a square bracket at the end and deleted the duplicate 'in' and it did the job!

Comment: Oopsie... I obviously wasn't paying attention when I wrote that. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

with open('coords.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = [tuple(map(int, row)) for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

print data
```

You could also do it incrementally using a generator function and avoid creating a huge list (unless that's your goal):

```
def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        for x, y in csv.reader(csvfile):
            yield int(x), int(y)

print list(get_data('coords.csv'))
```

Either way, this would be the output:

```
[(1, 2), (5, 6), (4, 4), (8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in l]
```